# Print specific pages from word file from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to print specific pages from a word file using Excel VBA, but I couldn't do that, I was only able to print the whole file and not the pages I wanted (changes according the value of LastPage). This is the code I used. Please help with that, thanks.

```
Sub PrintFile()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc  As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:file.docx")
objWord.Visible = False
objDoc.PrintOut from:="1", To:="LastPage".value
objWord.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting an error on the line starting `objDoc.PrintOut` then replace that line with

```
objDoc.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="1", To:=CStr(LastPage)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
But it gives me an error message variable [wdPrintFromTo] is not defined 
Office 365

Comment: @moudy - That is because you have, unwisely, not set a reference to the Word library, meaning you are using Late Binding. When coding across Office applications Late Binding is never the best approach. From the VBE choose Tools | References and check the box next to the entry for Microsoft Word. Doing this will allow your code to precompile, as well as giving you access to IntelliSense and the object browser. Alternatively, if you insist on using Late Binding, you can replace the Word enumeration, `wdPrintFromTo`, with its value, 3.